# Anything like Twitter Bootstrap for Android?

Tags: android

if you are a developer and have little clue about designs - Twitter Bootstrapt saves the day (at least for me).

Is there something similar for android (native, not web)? Because at least for me the default buttons, and black background looks truly ugly (same as plain browser buttons, which Twitter Bootstrap makes so nice looking)

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html gives some icons, and fonts, but maybe there is more ?

Comment: There seems to be no ready made theme available for Android, similar to bootstrap. I am new to Android and have not been able to locate one yet.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### [Android Bootstrap](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap)

I recently came across this project and it that looks very promising.

[image: Sample resources provided]

#### List of Features:

- Bootstrap buttons as per Bootstrap v3
- Rounded buttons
- Disabled buttons
- Various sized buttons (large to extra small)
- Just text buttons
- Left, right, left and right, or just icon button
- Font Awesome text as per Font Awesome v4
- Animations to Font Awesome Text items
- EditText backgrounds

Comment: IMHO the only actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 24):

just released two days ago and already has 100+ stars

https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap

Comment: It seems too logic focused as opposed to UI focused. Although things like maven, testing suites, etc. are all well and good, they don't really belong in what I've understood to be a UI package (a la twitter bootstrap).

Answer (score 8):

The Android Holo theme codifies the UX guidelines into a theme that you can use on Android. If you are not targeting 4.0, try this project that ported a lot of the theme all the way back to 1.6. I haven't tried it myself yet but may be a good start.

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution but I use Twitter Bootstrap and Phonegap which gives me the added advantage of multiple apps on different platforms.
I know you did mention native but I wonder if more people are leaning towards these solutions at least with even Windows joining the fray and having to develop for 4 different platforms.

Comment: The problem we have going the web app route is data. Our apps already move a lot of data between the device and the server, and the added overhead of having to move all that html / css / js, coupled with not so stellar data speeds make the web route seem really lackluster to us.

Answer (score 1):

Although the following are not focussed on the design part they nonetheless generate a project to start with for you:

- [AndroidKickstartR](http://androidkickstartr.com)
- [mvn archetype:generate](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-project-with-maven-template/)

On the second I recommend running the following command to filter Android projects from the list:

```
mvn archetype:generate | grep ndroid
```

It will list at least the following project templates:

```
 50: remote -> com.googlecode.android-player-root-archetype:parent-archetype (-)
115: remote -> com.vektorsoft.demux.tools:demux-android-archetype (Create Android application structure for DEMUX Framework applications)
123: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-gcm-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for a GCM Android application)
124: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-library-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android library)
125: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android application)
126: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-release (Creates a skeleton for an Android application,
127: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-with-test (Creates a skeleton for an Android application and instrumentation tests)
128: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:stand-archetype (Creates a skeleton for an Android application using the Stand framework stack)
555: remote -> org.eclipse.xtend:xtend-android-archetype (-)
857: remote -> ru.nikitav.android.archetypes:release (-)
858: remote -> ru.nikitav.android.archetypes:release-robolectric (-)
```