# Twitter bootstrap Holo theme

Tags: android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I serve [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) themes to my visitors. But I look for some theme that is similar to Android Holo theme (or any theme that looks familiar to Android users). Are there any css files that you see that makes default Twitter Bootstrap 3 UI, just like an Android app.

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778026/anything-like-twitter-bootstrap-for-android) question is unrelated)

(Main problem is to find a theme which looks similar to Holo theme. But while asking the question, I meaned that how can default Bootstrap theme can be changed easily to fit Holo theme UI.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Holo style theme/template based on the latest Bootstrap (3.0.2)

http://bootply.com/render/91970

http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/holo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any particular file, that changes the whole Bootstrap theme to kinda holo theme.

But you can at least reach a dark theme by already implemented inverted styles of bootstrap.

For example `navbar-inverse`. Same for Buttons, Labels and so on. You can look them all up at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Just search page for "inverse".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for regarding the Holo style, but a quick google seach shows something like this [Dark Holo Cards](http://mycolorscreen.com/2013/01/27/dark-holo-cards-by-thand/). You could perhaps take the time to use Bootstraps own [Theme Customiser](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) to create a look that you wanted, and then incorporate the [Droid Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans) font from Google Webfonts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there are any themes that look exactly like Android Holo, but here are a few that I think capture the essence of Holo.  (i.e Dark, Flat, ect.)

[chakra-dark](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/chakra-responsive-one-page-template-WB09X376J)

[prime.io](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/prime.io-WB008U70J)

Good Luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: and this one too
https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/flatjack-responsive-retina-ready-theme-WB0358991